# I can't return an api's body with RUBY ​and RSPEC

Tags: ruby, api, rspec

When validating if the api returns 200 OK, but when I list the API body with puts I'm not getting the list of values. The api I'm using is from the website: https://reqres.in/

```
**file spec_helper.rb**
require 'httparty'
require 'httparty/request'
require 'httparty/response/headers'
require  'json'

require_relative '../services/user_service.rb'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  include User
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
  expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
  mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
  Kernel.srand config.seed
end


**file user_service.rb**
module User
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://regres.in'
  format :json
end

describe 'agrupando os metodos de verbo GET' do

  it 'my first test - list users' do
    @users = User.get('/api/users?page=2')
    puts @users  ***// my problem is here!!!***
    puts expect(@users.code).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

Comment: If you `pp @users`, what's the actual output?

Comment: Failure/Error: pp @users

     JSON::ParserError:
       809: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
       <html>

Comment: That means you're getting an HTML page, not a JSON object. You likely need to make a different call or endpoint, or use a different method to extract the HTTP status code from your GET request.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not finding a solution for this.

Comment: Despite it's not a good idea to make real requests in the tests...You may try to use curl or browsers to open the URL to see the actual results first, or read API provider's documentation to see how to get the JSON response from the API

Comment: I'm asking for help and you ask me to read the manual!!! ..I honestly don't understand..